# What is the best way to recieve a $10,000 gift when you need some but not all of it immediately?

Tags: united-states, gift-tax, gifts

In the next 3 weeks I will be moving to a new location - my parents have set aside $10,000 for us.

My parents can transfer this money from their account to my account - because we share a credit union - but I am concerned about tax payments that I might need to make from receiving this gift.

Ideally, if I were to receive the whole amount, I would use the amount I need for our upcoming move and put the rest into a CD - although my parents have offered to give some of the gift to us, and put the rest into a CD in our name.

---

The short of it is - what is the best way for me to receive this gift from my parents while minimizing any taxes I or my parents would need to pay?

For context - I live in the United States, both my parents and I live in New York, and I will be moving to Maryland in July.

Comment: The potential duplicate above is slightly outdated, the annual exclusion is now $15k per person, so a married couple can gift another married couple up to $60k without gift tax consequences.

Answer (score 1):

First, gift taxes are on the giver, never the recipient.  No matter what, if it is truly a gift, which it sounds like this is, it will not be considered taxable income for you.

Second, there is an annual gift tax exclusion of $15,000 per person.  This means that gifts under this amount are not reportable or taxable for the giver.  And the amounts double if the giver or the recipient are married, which means that if your parents are married, they can collectively give you $30,000, and if you are married, they can give your spouse another $30,000, all without reporting or paying tax on the gift.  Above these amounts, the gift is reportable (on [IRS Form 709](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-709)), but there are lifetime exclusion amounts before the gift is actually taxable.

To explicitly answer your question, this gift of $10,000 has no tax implications whatsoever.

Comment: Gift over $15,000 require the filing of an IRS form 709. No taxes will need to paid nor will any of the lifetime exemption be consumed so long as the limits above are met. But any gift over $15,000 requires a 709 form be filed with the IRS.